# Ruby Unsigned Right Shift

Tags: java, ruby, bit-manipulation, unsigned

I have a snippet of java code:
`return (int)(seed >>> (48 - bits));`

As you can see it uses the unsigned right shift operator (>>>). I'm trying to implement this code in ruby which has no unsigned right shift operator, only a signed right shift operator. As I'm not very familiar with the >>> operator I'm not quite sure on how I'd impelemnt this in ruby. I tried doing a few searches to see if anyone had come across this problem before, but couldn't find anything relevent. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What is the range of values for `seed`? Positive or signed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unsigned shift operator can easily be implemented using simple bit shifting and masking:

```
public static int unsignedShift(int amt, int val) {
    int mask = (1 << (32 - amt)) - 1;   
    return (val >> amt) & mask;
}
```

The mask works by setting all bits to 1 that should be retained after the shift. Note that this returns different results compared to Java for amt >= 32 and amt = 0.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the technique, but this code doesn't look like Ruby. It looks like JavaScript which supports the unsigned shift operator.

Comment: @Jared It's Java but that's just to demonstrate the principle. Should be trivial to port to any other language.